# Google seach console: my sitemap status is 'Success' but with 0 discovered urls

Tags: indexing, seo, google-search-console, google-index

I have two problems with the Google search console:

1. I inserted in the Google search console the sitemap copied from Yoast, according to this format: https://yourwebsite.com/sitemap_index.xml. The sitemap was loaded and read (read yesterday, 15/7/23) but the discovered URLs are 0. I don't understand why.
2. Just 2 pages are indexed according to the Google search console, but I do not find them in the Google search. Could it be because I didn't set keywords for that pages?
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue before. You should generate a new sitemap and update the root folder , and after that, submit xml sitemap in Google Search Console.

Comment: Thanks Sachin, what do you mean by "generate e new sitemap and update the root folder"? I have just copied this link from YOAST and inserted in google search console (https://yourwebsite.com/sitemap_index.xml). I have just checked the link and it is updated